# Being 1 std away from the mean in a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I believe I have some misunderstanding in probability theory. In a normal distribution, we know the % of being $m$ std's from the mean. Can we do the same for a binomial distribution? for example, lets say $x\sim Bin(n,0.5)$, then the expected value is $n/2$ and the std is $\sqrt{n/4}$. Now since the binomial distribution is symmetric, $x$ will be above it's mean $50$% of the time. Can I tell at what percentage $x$ will be above the mean $+ 1$ std? Is there a general formula for $n$?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

To get the probability of x being below the mean + 1 std, you just need to evaluate the cdf of the binomial distribution at that point. In this case:

\begin{align}
F\left (n/2 + \sqrt{n/4} \right ) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 + \sqrt{n/4}\rfloor}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
i
\end{array}\right) 0.5^i(1-0.5)^{n-i}
\end{align}